# Trying to scanf but can't access a value it unless inputting another value

Tags: c, scanf

I am trying to dynamically initialize an array, but when I enter the `while` loop the first time `printf` prints the statement, but the next `printf` statement doesn't execute unless I put another value. I want to put values between

```
0--->n-1
```

First time `printf` statement executed but the 2nd time does not execute unless I enter any value. tried to enter 5 for the size, and put 0,1,2,3,4 for the values.

```
  #include <stdio.h>
   #include <malloc.h>
void main() {
    Ex5();
    system("pause");
}

void Ex5()
{
    int size_a,n_res=0,res=0;
    int *arr_a = input_array_dyn(&size_a);
         res = includes(arr_a, size_a);
         printf("res is %d ", res);
         free(arr_a);
    }


int* input_array_dyn(int *size) {
    int i=0, *p_to_arr;
    printf("enter size of arr:");
    scanf_s("%d", size);
    p_to_arr = (int*)calloc(*size,sizeof(int));
    while(i<*size) {
        printf("enter %d element", i);
        scanf_s(" %d ", &p_to_arr[i]);
        i++;
    }
    return p_to_arr;
}
```

Comment: could you please provide the exact input and the resulting output for a better understanding

Comment: Buffering issue? Output to `stdout` (where `printf` writes) is by default *line buffered*, meaning that the buffer will flushed (actually written) when you print a newline.

Comment: Consider separating `input_array_dyn()` into two functions: one to get `size`, and another to get the actual array. That way you will not need a pointer to size, and you won't need to `calloc()`, because you will be able to create the array in `Ex5` by knowing size before calling the function that asks the user for the array. Also you won't have to `free()`.

Comment: the posted code does not compile!  it is missing the prototype statements, it is missing the needed `#include` statements.  Without code that compiles, why should we guess as to the contents of the parts that are missing. We are not mind readers.  Please post a [mcve]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The format string in

```
scanf_s(" %d ", &p_to_arr[i]);
```

is troublesome and could possibly be the cause of your problem.

The problem with the format string is the trailing space. The trailing space means that `scanf_s` will read all trailing space characters, until there are no more spaces. The problem is that for `scanf_s` to know there are no more spaces, you must enter some non-space input.

This leads to `scanf_s` blocking until you write a second input.

The solution is to not have any spaces in the format string at all:

```
scanf_s("%d", &p_to_arr[i]);
```

The leading space isn't needed either, as the `"%d"` specifier will skip leading space automatically.

Comment: Correct me if wrong.  I think the second call to `scanf_s()` will have the newline from the enter key stored in memory from the first call.  If you remove the leading space, it will read that new line, which wasn't parsed by the first call, and stop there, so no number will be read

Comment: @CacahueteFrito The enter key will be put into the input buffer as a newline, which is a white-space characters. And as such will be skipped over and ignored by the `"%d"` format specifier.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know that.  However I'd still put the space because it doesn't hurt, and it is more explicit with the intention.

Comment: @CacahueteFrito The *leading* space only, I hope you mean? :)

Comment: So, is it that %c and %s are the only specifiers that don't discard spaces? Another thing I learnt today. This is going to be my next question if it isn't already there.

Comment: @CacahueteFrito `"%s"` also discards leading whitespace. From [this `scanf` (and family) reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf): "All conversion specifiers other than [, c, and n consume and discard all leading whitespace characters"

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, changing the format of the second `scanf` to `"%d"` should help. I've tested it locally and I'm able to enter all the values at once.